# Determine if range is in closed range

Tags: excel, vba, range

I would like to determine if rngA is in a closed range like rngB.

The functions UNION and INTERSECT won't do the trick.[image]

```
Sub InnerRange()

Dim rngA As Range
Dim rngB As Range

Dim i As Range

Set rngA = Range("H6")
Set rngB = Range("E4:J4,J5:J8,E8:I8,E5:E7")

Union(rngA, rngB).Select
```

End Sub

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the code is in an image. [idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: I've added the code...

Comment: Will A and B both be contiguous?

Answer (score 1):

This should be able to handle contiguous and non-contiguous ranges for A and B. Pass `rngA` and `rngB` to `IsIn`. It will return true if `rngA` is enclosed within `rngB`:

```
Option Explicit

Dim lngRowMin As Long
Dim lngRowMax As Long
Dim lngColMin As Long
Dim lngColMax As Long
Dim blnMap() As Boolean

Public Function IsIn(rngInner As Range, rngOuter As Range) As Boolean
    If (rngInner.Rows.Count > rngOuter.Rows.Count) Or (rngInner.Columns.Count > rngOuter.Columns.Count) Or (rngInner.Row < rngOuter.Row) Then
        Exit Function
    End If

    Dim cel As Range
    Dim lngInnerCoord As Long
    Dim lngOuterCoord As Long
    Dim lngCoord As Long
    Dim lngOuterCoords() As Long
    Dim lngInnerCoords() As Long

    ReDim lngOuterCoords(1 To rngOuter.Count, 1 To 2)
    ReDim lngInnerCoords(1 To rngInner.Count, 1 To 2)
    lngRowMin = rngOuter.Row
    lngRowMax = lngRowMin
    lngColMin = rngOuter.Column
    lngColMax = lngColMin

    For Each cel In rngOuter
        lngOuterCoord = lngOuterCoord + 1
        lngOuterCoords(lngOuterCoord, 1) = cel.Row
        lngOuterCoords(lngOuterCoord, 2) = cel.Column

        If lngOuterCoords(lngOuterCoord, 1) > lngRowMax Then
            lngRowMax = lngOuterCoords(lngOuterCoord, 1)
        ElseIf lngOuterCoords(lngOuterCoord, 1) < lngRowMin Then
            lngRowMin = lngOuterCoords(lngOuterCoord, 1)
        End If

        If lngOuterCoords(lngOuterCoord, 2) > lngColMax Then
            lngColMax = cel.Column
        ElseIf lngOuterCoords(lngOuterCoord, 2) < lngColMin Then
            lngColMin = lngOuterCoords(lngOuterCoord, 2)
        End If
    Next cel

    For Each cel In rngInner
        lngInnerCoord = lngInnerCoord + 1
        lngInnerCoords(lngInnerCoord, 1) = cel.Row
        lngInnerCoords(lngInnerCoord, 2) = cel.Column

        If lngInnerCoords(lngInnerCoord, 1) > lngRowMax Then
            Exit Function
        ElseIf lngInnerCoords(lngInnerCoord, 1) < lngRowMin Then
            Exit Function
        End If

        If lngInnerCoords(lngInnerCoord, 2) > lngColMax Then
            Exit Function
        ElseIf lngInnerCoords(lngInnerCoord, 2) < lngColMin Then
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next cel

    ReDim blnMap(lngRowMin To lngRowMax, lngColMin To lngColMax)

    For lngCoord = 1 To lngOuterCoord
        blnMap(lngOuterCoords(lngCoord, 1), lngOuterCoords(lngCoord, 2)) = True
    Next lngCoord

    For lngCoord = 1 To lngInnerCoord
        If Not InnerTrap(lngInnerCoords(lngCoord, 1), lngInnerCoords(lngCoord, 2)) Then Exit Function
    Next lngCoord

    IsIn = True
End Function

Private Function InnerTrap(lngRow As Long, lngCol As Long) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo Escaped

    If Not blnMap(lngRow, lngCol) Then
        blnMap(lngRow, lngCol) = True
        If Not InnerTrap(lngRow + 1, lngCol) Then Exit Function
        If Not InnerTrap(lngRow - 1, lngCol) Then Exit Function
        If Not InnerTrap(lngRow, lngCol + 1) Then Exit Function
        If Not InnerTrap(lngRow, lngCol - 1) Then Exit Function
    End If

    InnerTrap = True
Escaped:

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work with contiguous range:

```
Sub FindInnerRange()

    Dim rngA As Range, rngB As Range

    Set rngA = Range("H8")
    Set rngB = Range("E4:J4,J5:J8,E8:I8,E5:E7")

    MsgBox rngA.Address & " is" _
           & IIf(Not Intersect(rngA, Intersect(rngB.EntireRow, rngB.EntireColumn)) Is Nothing And Intersect(rngA, rngB) Is Nothing, "", " NOT") _
           & " in a closed range " & rngB.Address, vbCritical

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If the outer range really is enclosing then you can use CurrentRegion

```
Sub InnerRange()

Dim rngA As Range
Dim rngB As Range
Dim rngC As Range
Dim rngD As Range

    Dim i As Range

    Set rngA = Range("H6")
    Set rngB = Range("E4:J4,J5:J8,E8:I8,E5:E7")

    Set rngC = rngB.CurrentRegion
    Set rngD = Intersect(rngC, rngA)
    Debug.Print rngD.Address
    End Sub
```